# PHP/Javascript - Add payment method with Stripe API

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I am using Wordpress, but I am using an "out of the box" solution because my client requested it specifically. I have this Javascript which creates a form and when the form is submitted it creates a cookie with the token in it, so I can retrieve it from PHP, it looks like this:

```
<form action="/wp-content/themes/betheme/includes/add_payment_method.php" method="post" id="add-card-form">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="card-element">
          Credit or debit card
        </label>

        <div id="card-element"></div>

        <!-- Used to display Element errors. -->
        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
      </div>

      <button>Add payment method</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

    <script>
        var style = {
          base: {
            color: '#ffffff',
            fontSize: '14px',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
            '::placeholder': {
              color: '#ccc',
            },
            iconColor: "#fff"
          },
          invalid: {
            color: '#e5424d',
            ':focus': {
              color: '#303238',
            },
          },
        };
        var stripe = Stripe('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        var elements = stripe.elements();
        var cardElement = elements.create('card', {style: style, hidePostalCode: true});

        window.mobilecheck = function() {
          var check = false;
          (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
          return check;
        };

        if(mobilecheck()) {
            cardElement.mount('#Content > div > div > div > div.section.mcb-section.hide-desktop > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > form > div.form-row >div#card-element');
        }
        else {
            cardElement.mount('#Content > div > div > div > div.section.mcb-section.hide-tablet.hide-mobile > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > form > div.form-row > div#card-element');
        }

        cardElement.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
          var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
          if (event.error) {
            displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
          } else {
            displayError.textContent = '';
          }
        });

        // Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.
        var form = document.getElementById('add-card-form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          stripe.createToken(cardElement).then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
              // Inform the customer that there was an error.
              var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
              errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
              // Send the token to your server.
              stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
            }
          });
        });

        function createCookie(name, value, days) {
          var expires;
          if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
          } else {
           expires = "";
          }
          document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
        }

        function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
            createCookie("stripe_token", token, 1);

            var form = document.getElementById('add-card-form');
            form.submit();
        }
</script>
```

When the form is submitted, it executes this PHP in `add_payment_method.php`:

```
<?php
    require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");
    submit_stripe_payment_method($_COOKIE['stripe_token']);
?>
```

In my `functions.php` file for my theme, I have:

```
require_once('stripe-php/init.php');

....

function submit_stripe_payment_method($token) {
    print_r($token);

    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    echo 'Your User ID is: ' .$current_user_id;

    $customer_id = get_user_meta( $current_user_id, '_stripe_customer_id', true );
    echo "CUSTOMER_ID: ".(string)$customer_id;

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    echo "MADE IT HERE";

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve((string)$customer_id);

    echo "CUSTOMER: ".$customer;

    $customer_card = $customer->sources->create(["source" => $token]);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($customer_card);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

The output of the above is:

`[object Object]Your User ID is: 1CUSTOMER_ID: cus_DsoF18uw1dR0ujMADE IT HERE`

As you can see it only gets as far as "MADE IT HERE" `echo`.

I have verified in the Stripe web console that the `$customer_id` I am using is correct, and I don't have any errors, PHP or otherwise. The only thing I can think of is I am using the token wrong but it seems pretty straight forward. As you can see, the `$token` prints as [Object object], and it does this no matter how I try to log it, so I can't see exactly what it is, but this makes sense because it contains sensitive information used to validate the credit card...also maybe it never gets to that point because I never see the `echo "CUSTOMER: ".$customer;` statement, so maybe it gets hung up on:

`$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve((string)$customer_id);`

Also, I tried the above without `(string)` first but got the same result.

So after all of this, I check the Stripe console, and no card has been added.

**UPDATE**

Apparently the API version I am using is not the latest version, I can upgrade, I just want to know if anyone thinks this is a possible solution before I do it. As it might change how stripe works throughout the site (with the plugin). I am using `2018-02-28` and I can upgrade to `2018-09-24`
. I am also testing on `localhost` environment so I am not `https`, but I don't think this matters for testing.

**UPDATE**

I realized I hadn't added the endpoint for my `localhost` setup to the `stripe` console admin area. To do this I had to use `ngrok` (as suggested by Stripe if you are using `localhost`). I am using `localhost` on port `8888`, so I did `./ngrok http 8888` and then tried again and it didn't work. It does say in Wordpress that the endpoint will `enable you to receive notifications on the charge statuses.` So maybe it isn't relevant for adding a payment method. I used the `http` url for `ngrok` not the `https` url.

**UPDATE**

I manually installed `stripe-php` so I tried with `composer` but it didn't help, same result.

**UPDATE**

I changed my key to the `secret key` and that allowed me to retrieve the `$customer` but I don't see any output for `$customer_card` and when I look in the dashboard no card has been created.

**UPDATE**

I checked the `Stripe` dashboard and I am receiving an error when I try to create the source:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such token: [object Object]",
    "param": "source",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong with the token?

**UPDATE**

Solution to token problem: in test mode, the token is just a string that corresponds with the test credit card number you are using, I needed `"tok_visa"` for `4242424242424242`. https://stripe.com/docs/testing

Comment: You should tried like `print_r($customer); die;` instead of `echo $customer`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be that 
in line

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

you are using `Publishable key` starts with `pk_xxx`, instead you should be using `Secret Key` `sk_xxxx` in your account.

You could see the errors from Stripe Dashboard

https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs?method%5B%5D=get&method%5B%5D=post&method%5B%5D=delete&direction%5B%5D=connect_in&direction%5B%5D=self

after you login.

Let me know if that helps

**EDIT**

I also needed to use a testing token, which is just a string that corresponds to the the test credit card number you are using. https://stripe.com/docs/testing. See the `Tokens` tab.

Comment: thanks, this worked, I am able to retrieve the customer now, but the card with the token as the 'source' isn't being added, I will update my question with output. let me know if you have any ideas, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't call Stripe\PaymentMethod::attach() statically. You have to fetch the PaymentMethod first and then attach it to the Customer. The code should be:

$pm = \Stripe\PaymentMethod::retrieve('pm_123');
$pm->attach(['customer' => 'cus_123']);

I'll work on updating the docs to avoid that confusion!